# Changing url depth vs TinyMCE image insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I've written a plugin that allows users to add images to TinyMCE, which works.  The problem is that the saved html when displayed may vary depth in the URL - e.g. mysite.com/path/path/path/page.htm which would render any image links broken as the path depth changes.  I don't want to use absolute paths, is there a good approach to fixing this?

Comment: I think this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: Interesting, but I think i'd like to try and do it server-side as relying on javascript to fix things seems a bit wrong.

Comment: So what server side language are you using?

Comment: PHP.  I can think of a few approaches but they seem pretty hacky and am just wondering if TinyMCE has something for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use absolute paths you can configure tinymce using the init and the following

```
relative_urls : true,
document_base_url : "http://www.mysite.com/path_x/",
```

This will convert all URLs within the same domain to relative URLs. The URLs will be relative from the document_base_url. You may define the base URL as short as needed.

[Here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F) is a link to the possible tinymce settings concerning paths.

Comment: The problem is TinyMCE doesn't know the base path and the same entry can be used (theoretically) at multiple different path indentation levels.